# Compute the following integral $I=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\{x\}}{x^{3/2}.x^{i/2}}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Question:** Compute the integral $$I=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\{x\}}{x^{3/2}.x^{i/2}}dx \tag{1}$$
where $\{.\}$ denotes the fractional part function and $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

My try: We first show that the above integral converges.

$$|I|\leq\int_{1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\{x\}}{x^{3/2}.x^{i/2}}\right|dx $$
Since $|x^{i/2}|=1$ and $\{x\}<1$, so we get
$$|I|\leq\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}dx $$
So we get $$|I|\leq  2\tag{2}$$
Now we can write equation $(1)$ as:

$$I= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{\{x\}}{x^{3/2}.x^{i/2}}dx $$
So we have $$I= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{x-k}{x^{3/2}.x^{i/2}}dx $$
So we get$$I= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{k}^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{x^{(1+i)/2}}-\frac{k}{x^{(3+i)/2}}\right)dx $$
which gives $$I= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(2\frac{x^{(1-i)/2}}{1-i}+2k\frac{x^{-(1+i)/2}}{1+i}\right)\Biggr|_{k}^{k+1} $$
hence we have $$I= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left[\left(2\frac{(k+1)^{(1-i)/2}}{1-i}+2k\frac{(k+1)^{-(1+i)/2}}{1+i}\right)-\left(2\frac{k^{(1-i)/2}}{1-i}+2k\frac{k^{-(1+i)/2}}{1+i}\right)\right] $$
which implies that $$I= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left[\left(\frac{2(k+1)^{(1-i)/2}}{1-i}+2(k+1-1)\frac{(k+1)^{-(1+i)/2}}{1+i}\right)-\left(2\frac{k^{(1-i)/2}}{1-i}+2\frac{k^{(1-i)/2}}{1+i}\right)\right] $$
So we get $$I= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left[\left(2(k+1)^{(1-i)/2}-2\frac{(k+1)^{-(1+i)/2}}{1+i}\right)-2k^{(1-i)/2}\right] $$
Hence finally we have $$I= 2\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left[\left((k+1)^{(1-i)/2}-\frac{(k+1)^{-(1+i)/2}}{1+i}\right)-k^{(1-i)/2}\right] $$
Please give some insights.

Comment: Show that for $\Re(s) > 1$, $\zeta(s)=s\int_1^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor x^{-s-1}dx=\frac{s}{s-1} - s\int_1^\infty \{ x\} x^{-s-1}dx$ which by analytic continuation stays true for $\Re(s) > 0$

Comment: @reuns Thank you. Is my method incorrect? Can't we proceed like I have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to solve:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}:=\int_1^\infty\frac{\left\{x\right\}}{x^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Using the relation $\left\{x\right\}=x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$. So we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}=\int_1^\infty\frac{x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor}{x^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x=\int_1^\infty x^{1-\text{n}}\space\text{d}x-\int_1^\infty\frac{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor}{x^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x\tag2$$

It is not hard to see that when $\Re\left(\text{n}\right)>2$, we get:

$$\int_1^\infty x^{1-\text{n}}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\text{n}-2}\tag3$$

So:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}=\frac{1}{\text{n}-2}-\int_1^\infty\frac{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor}{x^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x\tag4$$

Now, we can note that:

$$\int_\alpha^\beta\frac{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor}{x^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x=\sum_{\text{k}\space=\space\alpha}^{\beta-1}\left(\text{k}\int_\text{k}^{\text{k}+1}\frac{x}{x^{\text{n}+1}}\space\text{d}x\right)\tag5$$

So, for your case we get:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}=\frac{1}{\text{n}-2}-\lim_{\beta\space\to\space\infty}\sum_{\text{k}\space=\space1}^{\beta-1}\left(\text{k}\int_\text{k}^{\text{k}+1}\frac{x}{x^{\text{n}+1}}\space\text{d}x\right)\tag6$$

And we can see that:

$$\text{k}\int_\text{k}^{\text{k}+1}\frac{x}{x^{\text{n}+1}}\space\text{d}x=\left[\frac{\text{k}x^{1-\text{n}}}{1-\text{n}}\right]_\text{k}^{\text{k}+1}=\frac{\text{k}\left(\text{k}+1\right)^{1-\text{n}}}{1-\text{n}}-\frac{\text{k}^{2-\text{n}}}{1-\text{n}}\tag7$$

So:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}=\frac{1}{\text{n}-2}-\frac{1}{1-\text{n}}\cdot\lim_{\beta\space\to\space\infty}\sum_{\text{k}\space=\space1}^{\beta-1}\left(\text{k}\left(\text{k}+1\right)^{1-\text{n}}-\text{k}^{2-\text{n}}\right)\tag8$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can't we simplify further? I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Mary You're welcome. I am not quite sure yet.

Comment: Ok please think about it and edit your answer. Take your time. Thanks

Comment: @Mary I'll, but for now I have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.....